# Running Sinatra server and subprocess asynchronously

Tags: ruby, multithreading, http, sinatra, thin

I am trying to run a process that processes flight tracking data and actively turns it into JSON strings (continuous looping process) alongside a Sinatra server that responds to GET requests with these JSON strings. I am trying to use threading to handle this but have had no success. How can I run these two processes side by side? Here are some more specifics:

I have a class `Aircraft` with an array of `Aircraft` objects called `Aircraft::All`. I have a method that continually updates this array that I want to run alongside a Sinatra server that responds to GET requests with the list of aircraft in JSON format.

Here is the code:

```
# starting the data stream from external process
IO.popen("./dump1090") do |data|
    block = ""
    # created sinatra server thread
    t1 = Thread.new do
        set :port, 8080
        set :environment, :production

        get '/aircrafts' do
            return_message = {}
            if !Aircraft::All.first.nil?
                return_message[:status] == 'success'
                return_message[:aircrafts] = message_maker
            else
                return_message[:status] = 'sorry - something went wrong'
                return_message[:aircrafts] = [] 
            end
            return_message.to_json
        end
    end
    # parsing the data in main thread -- the process 
    # I want to run alongside the server (parse_block updates Aircraft::All)
    while line = data.gets
        if line.to_s.split('').first == '*'
          parse_block(block)
          puts block
          Aircraft::All.reject { |aircraft| Time.now.to_f - aircraft.contact_time > 30 }
          block = ""  
        end
        block += line.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your concrete problem? Could you provide any code?

Comment: just edited my question to include the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the main thread is the Sinatra app and the additional thread loads the data, which is more usual to me.

```
class Aircraft
  @aircrafts = {}

  def self.all
    @aircrafts
  end
end

Thread.new do
  no = 1
  while true
    Aircraft.all[no] = 'Boing'
    no += 1
    sleep(3)
  end
end

get '/aircrafts' do
  Aircraft.all.to_json
end
```

Comment: I need an answer where Sinatra runs as the background process (or Thread).